# android which class provide definition to SharedPreferences interface

Tags: android, class, interface, sharedpreferences

if look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) it clearly shows it's an interface in Android SDK.

public interface SharedPreferences

Can anyone help me understand it better that which class exactly provides definition to functions of [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)?

Comment: Question is about implementation of [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), I know it's interface but not able to find which class give it definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an interface, there's no mistake in android's documentation. As you can see in [`SharedPreferences`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java)'s source code too:

```
public interface SharedPreferences {
```

Digging in android's source code, we can see that [`Activity`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L670) extends from `ContextWrapper`

```
public class Activity extends ContextThemeWrapper
    implements LayoutInflater.Factory2,
    Window.Callback, KeyEvent.Callback,
    OnCreateContextMenuListener, ComponentCallbacks2,
    Window.OnWindowDismissedCallback {
```

Looking at [ContextWrapper.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java), it calls `getSharedPreferences` function from `Context` class

```
Context mBase;

@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    return mBase.getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
}
```

Which is declared as an `abstract` function in [Context.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java#L624),

```
/**
 * Interface to global information about an application environment.  This is
 * an abstract class whose implementation is provided by
 * the Android system.  It
 * allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as
 * up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities,
 * broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.
 */
public abstract class Context {

    public abstract SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode);

}
```

In conclusion `SharedPreferences` is implemented in a `class`(as every `interface`) on every `Context` implementation. If we take a look at the comments in `Context`'s source code we can see that:

> This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the
>   Android system

And in case that you want more information about `Context`, here is way more info: [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301475/4343318)

Comment: Thanks Santiago - it helps me to understand exactly what I was looking for, but I don't know why someone give downvote to my question.

Comment: you're welcome. And yes, idk either, but here's +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

`getSharedpreference()` is the function of `ContextWrapper` class. And `ContextWrapper` class is extended by Every Activity class.

When we use `getSharedpreference()` method then it is called by context class. It is in the context class object. But it returns the `Sharedpreferences` object.
Shared preferences is not a class it is a interface. `getSharedpreference()` is use only reference of this interface.