# SharedPreferences : Is it a class or an interface?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm confused, please help me.

[Android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) say `SharedPreferences` is an **Interface** and also we can see on [grepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/SharedPreferences.java#SharedPreferences) that the SharedPreferences is an **Interface**.

But [developers.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) also says `SharedPreferences` is a **Class.**

They write.

> "The SharedPreferences **class** provides a general framework ..."

So, **SharedPreferences**  is a **Class** or an **Interface**?

Comment: It's interface http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/SharedPreferences.java#SharedPreferences

Answer (score 5):

The documentations is not wrong, but may be it is a bit confusing.

If you see the code, you'll see that [`SharedPreferences`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1a008c1/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java) is actually an interface. But as you mentioned, [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
it is referring to its implementation as class which is actually `SharedPreferencesImpl` and you can look into its implementation [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java). When you make a call to `getSharedPreferences()` method, it actually returns the object of `SharedPreferencesImpl` which is a class that implements `SharedPreferences` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [SharedPrefs](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/content/SharedPreferences.java#SharedPreferences) is an interface. It is implemented by [SharedPreferencesImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl) which provides us the functionality the doc speaks about shared prefs. Though the SharedPreferencesImpl has not been in the doc primarily, SharedPreferences has always been the face for the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

SharedPreferences is interface ,but implemented as a class. This conception is abstract factory ,a kind of Design Pattern. The declaration of SharedPreferences  is interface, but getSharedPreference() returns a class which implements SharedPreferences interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreferences is an interface. you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) that the Sharedpreferences has *Interface* as its parent.

> Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by getSharedPreferences(String, int). For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share.

For further reference you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34248952/4450098) answer.

Comment: He already has this link he just need to understand what is it.. One link is saying it's an **interface** and the other is saying it's a **class**

Comment: The second link says "The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types." It's seems like a mistake.